# mosaic transition effect between multiple images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I  have tried to make a mosaic effect to my carrousel

like this example :

http://burnmind.com/demos/mosaic/ not like this 100 % i want to have controls button next and previous and have images in html tag

but it doesn't work i want help

this is my work [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ebbnevu/3/)

i have make only next button for previous button it will be the same thing just i will replace position ++ with position--

Jquery Code :

```
$(function(){
  var $carroussel =   $('#carrousel'); 
    var $carrousselhover=$('#carrousel .hover');
    $carroussel.append('<div class="controls"> <span class="Previous"> <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/ip6n42rn3/previous.png"> </span> <span  class="Next">  <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/6yspmoyun/next.png">   </span> </div>');

var $nbrimage = $('#carrousel img').length-1 ;
    var $img = $('#carrousel img');

   var width = 700;
var height = 200;
 var horizontal_pieces = 8;
    var vertical_pieces = 6;
    total_pieces = horizontal_pieces * vertical_pieces;

    var box_width = width / horizontal_pieces;
    var box_height = height / vertical_pieces;
    var vertical_position = 0;
elements = new Array();
var count ;
count=0;
    var $position;
    $position=0;
    $carroussel.width(width).height(height);
    var $curentImage=$img.eq($position); // First image



    var listimage= $('#carrousel ul li');
    var tempEl;
  $('.controls .Next').click(function(){

      if($position<$nbrimage)
      {


          for (i=0; i<total_pieces; i++)
    {
        $curentImage= $img.eq($position);
         tempEl = $('<span class="hover" id="hover-' + i + '"></span>');

        var horizontal_position = (i % horizontal_pieces ) * box_width;

        if(i > 0 && i % horizontal_pieces == 0)
        {
            vertical_position += box_height;
        }

        tempEl.css({'background-position': '-' + horizontal_position + 'px -' + vertical_position + 'px',

                   'background-image': 'url('+$img.eq($position).attr('src')+')'});
        $img.eq($position).remove();
        listimage.eq($position).append(tempEl);
        elements.push(tempEl);
    }

       $position++;
      $carroussel.css({'background-image': 'url('+$img.eq($position).attr('src')+')'});
          $('#carrousel .hover').width(box_width).height(box_height);
         setInterval(toggleDisplay,10000);

      }
      else
      {
          $position=$nbrimage;
      }
       function toggleDisplay()
{
if(count>=total_pieces)
{
    clearInterval(0);


}
    else
    {
    var tempEl = elements[count];
    var opacity = tempEl.css('opacity');

    if(opacity == 0)
    {
        tempEl.animate({ opacity: 1 })
    }
    else
    {
        tempEl.animate({ opacity: 0 })
    }

    count = (count + 1) ;
    }


}
  } );


});
```

Css Code :

```
#carrousel{
    position:relative;

    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:2;
}
#carrousel ul li{
    position:absolute;
top:0px;
    left:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#carrousel .hover{
}
.controls
{
position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:1;

}

.controls .Next {
position: absolute;
right: 4px;
top: 30px;
}

.controls .Previous  {
position: absolute;
left:4px;
top: 30px;
}

.controls span:hover
{

    cursor:pointer;

}
```

Comment: None of the demos have any buttons to demonstrate changing slides to other backgrounds so it may be best to directly change the CSS background when you click forwards or backwards. ie top or bottom image. i managed to do this basic demo without buttons -- http://jsfiddle.net/7nr1aqdw/ -- let me see if i can add the buttons and change the image dynamically

Comment: Yes I know that None of the demos have any buttons just for explain you what i want to ashieve. but with button next and previous and with my html  with tag images not like demos  and that what i have tried to do but opacity have always number of 0 if you inspect element in browser

Comment: Well i managed to change the images, its a basic demo, not sure how many images you will have but its a start.  -- http://jsfiddle.net/vzqod1zL/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could cut the image you want to transition into smaller segments (with something like Photoshop). Then just animate them to align back and form the original image.

Hope it helps :)